How to check if durable function is already running (worker isolated)?
  [Function(FunctionNames.BuildingsStart)]
  public async Task HttpRun(
      [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
      [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient starter)
  {

     Check required here to Return if function BuildingsOrchestration is already running.
     How is BuildingsOrchestration started if check confirms it is not running?

     
      await starter.StartNewAsync<string>(FunctionNames.BuildingsOrchestration, null);
  }

Have removed webjobs

This used to work a few years ago. I am not sure if that helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46675944/how-to-get-runtime-status-of-queue-triggered-azure-function/47690679#47690679

It'll be in-process, the date is some years ago. Am refactoring for 'isolated worker'

To check the status of .NET 8 isolated durable function, you have to use DurableTaskClient.GetInstancesAsync(instanceName, true); as stated in GitHub issue.
Function.cs:

[Function("Function1_HttpStart")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpStart(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
    [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
    FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("Function1_HttpStart");

            // Function input comes from the request content.
            string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
                nameof(Function1));

           var result= client.GetInstancesAsync(instanceId, true);

            logger.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);
            logger.LogInformation(result.ToString());
            return client.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }

Program.cs:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
        });
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

Response:


References:
Also refer the SO solution by @SiddheshDesai.
